# does dynamic library shared global variable in linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

As we know, linux call `ldconfig` to load all `*.so` libraries and then link the applications who use the shared library. However, I am confused how the global variable is working in this case. Since there is only one copy of shared library across all these application, do they share the global variables in the shared library? If yes, then how they synchronize?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not shared - the code/text section of the library is shared - the data portion is unique to each process that uses the library

Comment: Thanks! BTW, do you have any web links about the dynamic loader, i.e. how does it work.

Comment: The `ld.so` dynamic linker is free software (so you could study its source code and improve it), and uses the `mmap` system call to project some `.so` segments into virtual address space of the process. You could `strace` your program to get a feeling of involved system calls.

Comment: BTW, `ld.so`, not `ldconfig`, is doing the dynamic linking. `ldconfig` is just configuring that dynamic linker.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented:

- Levine's book on [linkers and loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) is a useful reference.
- Linux dynamic linker `ld.so` is free software, part of [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and you can study and improve its source code
- the dynamic linker is `ld.so` not `ldconfig` (which just updated cached information used by `ld.so`).
- the `ld.so` linker is using the [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) system call to project some `.so` segments into the virtual address space of the process; the "text" segment (for code and read-only constants) uses `MAP_SHARED` with `PROT_READ`. The "data" segment (for global or static variables in C or C++) uses `MAP_PRIVATE` with `PROT_WRITE`
- you would learn a lot by `strace`-ing your program to get a feeling of the involved system calls.