# Shared libraries and global std::string issues on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, static-members

I have a class consisting purely of class statics in one `.so`, which gets called from various other `.so`s, but on program exit under `valgrind` I get a double free error that says:

```
==23162== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
...
==23162==  Address 0xe187d70 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 97 free'd
...
==23162==  Block was alloc'd at
....
==23162==    by 0x165C0C90: FileManager::setCommonConfigFolder(...)
             (in .../lib2.so)
```

The code is actually in `lib1.so`, but called from `lib2.so`.

Looking around, I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12452250/1270789):

> No it is not shared - the code/text section of the library is shared - the data portion is unique to each process that uses the library

So what is the timing for freeing static objects allocated by the actions of the client of the library? How do I avoid this problem?

The relevant portions of the code are as follows. This is compiled into `lib1.so` and called from `lib2.so` and `lib3.so`. With suitable logging, I can see that the address in the `valgrind` report `Address 0xe187d70 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 97 free'd` is indeed `mCommonConfigDirectory.data`.

#### FileManager.cpp

```
#include "FileManager.h"
#include <string>

std::string FileManager::mCommonConfigDirectory = "../common/config";

void FileManager::setCommonConfigFolder (std::string const& configPath)
{
    mCommonConfigDirectory = configPath;
}
```

#### FileManager.h

```
#include <string>

class FileManager
{
public:
    static void setCommonConfigFolder (std::string const& configPath);

protected:
    static std::string mCommonConfigDirectory;
};
```

Comment: post [mcve] please

Comment: "I have a class consisting purely of class statics". That would probably be a design error, but it doesn't by itself cause a double freeing. You need to find out where the block was freed the first time.

Comment: @n.m. In my defense, I inherited the code. The memory appears to be freed once for each `.so` that uses it. So does that imply that the class statics end up in a separate section that loads only once along with the code and text, not multiple times with the data for the processes that use the library? But that doesn't fit with what I am observing...

Comment: Hmm, I made my class [into a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/1270789) and the problem goes away, and the addresses of `mCommonConfigDirectory.data` looks much better.

Comment: "The memory appears to be freed once for each .so that uses it" This is not supposed to happen. Either there's one copy of the variable, and it gets destroyed once; or there are multiple copies at different addresses, and they don't interfere with each other.